# Sharepoint 2007 Retain Form Data after submit

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath

We have a form to log call information.  Originally it was supposed to be one call = one log.  But now it needs to change to one call = multiple logs.  However, the contact information (name/company/region) does not change.  The only thing that would change in each log would be the reason for call.

I tried the following, to no avail: http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/27541/95388.aspx

I have a Save Call button which will submit the form and then open a new form, ready for the next call.

I have added a Save Log button which I want to submit the form information, open a new form but retain the contact information (name/company/region).  The reason for call drop down would reset to blank.

Its simple but I havent found a way to get this working in InfoPath.  Keep in mind I am a novice user, so coding is my last ditch hope for this.  I would like - if its possible - to have the Save Log button run off a set of rules - but sadly, it doesnt open a new form after I submit the form.

Any help advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, I can think of two workarounds.

1. There is a separate list for logs. The only use of your InfoPath form is just to fill out the information. After you press "submit", it will not close the form but save the form and triggers a workflow (SharePoint Designer) and will "create a list item" on the separate list. The values are pulled from your InfoPath form and the workflow will use it to create the item on the separate list.
  I've tried this path. My requirement is One Request Form with multiple Tasks. The user can add tasks on the form without closing it.

  So in the end, One Form = Multiple Tasks
2. Using the form library only. You can try submitting the form with unique file name. Every press of "submit" button, the form will be saved with a unique filename. It is configured on Submit Data Connection.

Let me know if you wan more clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

1. So I see what you are saying - essentially have two lists, one for the contact information and the second for the log information.   I'm just not sure how you would set this up.  Also, if people want to view the list information - how would you create a view that would join both lists?

2. I can try the unique filename option.  I presume you mean the ID field - change that value after a submit?

Comment: What I've tried on one of my project is that the logs associated on the form are displayed in some king of a table. One form=multiple logs. You can use query rule on one field on change so it will be refreshed and pull the updated logs.

Comment: For the unique filename, I'm using the now() function since it shows the seconds. Use substring functions to only get the numbers. It will be more unique since every seconds is ticking and submitting the logs will ensure a unique filename